# Unable to install packages uzing pip or pip3

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I am getting the following error while trying to make a pip package installation:

```
# sudo pip3 install fb-re2
Collecting fb-re2
  Using cached fb-re2-1.0.7.tar.gz (9.4 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: fb-re2
  Building wheel for fb-re2 (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [15 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310
      copying re2.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-310
      running build_ext
      building '_re2' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c _re2.cc -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/_re2.o -std=c++11
      _re2.cc:37:10: fatal error: re2/re2.h: No such file or directory
         37 | #include <re2/re2.h>
            |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
      compilation terminated.
      error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for fb-re2
  Running setup.py clean for fb-re2
Failed to build fb-re2
ERROR: Could not build wheels for fb-re2, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Tried several options to install it. But no luck. Please help.

Tried several steps like those below:

```
   65  pip install wheel setuptools pip --upgrade
   66  pip3 install wheel setuptools pip --upgrade
   67  sudo pip3 install .
   68  pip3 install wheel
   69  pip install fb-re2 --no-cache-dir
   70  pip3 install fb-re2 --no-cache-dir
   71  pip install wheel
   72  apt install fb-re2
   73  apt update -y
   74  pip install localpip
   75  localpip install fb-re2
   76  sudo pip3 install fb-re2  --no-binary :all:
   77  sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev
   78  pip install -U pip setuptools
   79  sudo pip3 install fb-re2
```

Comment: Have you installed [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/)? `sudo apt install libre2-dev`

Comment: Yes, the following steps corrected the issue

`
1. apt-get install libre2-dev

2. wget -c https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4b/39/e2f57ddd1c00c54e2a3a868d2ebb2c8674325e42308e88e2ae4842d03bc0/fb-re2-1.0.7.tar.gz

3. python3 -m pip install fb-re2-1.0.7.tar.gz

`

Thank you